# Godot iOS touch screen button

Tags: ios, godot

I'm working on a 2d game and the build works fine on Android but when play it on iOS the touchscreen button does not work as expected:
I have to "long press" the button before the character moves, unlike Android where it works instantly by touch.

Is there any option or something I'm missing that could make the character move instantly by touch on iOS (without having to long press the button)?

I used the movement doc for 2d in the godot official documentation.

Godot version 3.2.2

Comment: Can you share the link of the documentation you followed?